# Quiero crear un informe de mi base de datos con Jasper

Tags: java

```
   /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package pruebajasperreport;

    import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;

    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
    import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;


    public class PruebaJasperReport {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {
            // TODO code application logic here
            crearInforme();
        }

        private static void crearInforme() throws JRException {
            String reportSource = "src\\template\\template1.jrxml";
            String reportDest = "src\\results\\Informe1.html";
            Connection conn;
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

            try {
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/musicos";
                conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");

    // cuando ya está compilado JasperReport informe = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(reportSource);
                JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
                System.out.print(jasperReport.getColumnCount());
                JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);

                JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, reportDest);

                JasperViewer vista = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
                vista.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                vista.setVisible(true);

            } catch (SQLException | JRException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }}
```

Quiero crear un informe y que se visualice en pantalla, pero no funciona por el siguiente error, quiero saber donde está mi fallo, ya que no se muy bien que hacer, el error se da en la linea

> JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

y quiero saber como solventarlo, he conectado a la base de datos el programa e introducido los paquetes tanto de **mysql** como de **jasper**, pero sigue sin solventarse, quiero sacar el informe en formato html a partir del jxml que he creado con el Wizard de Jasper

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:82)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.loadProperties(JRPropertiesUtil.java:101)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.initProperties(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:94)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<init>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:71)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<clinit>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getDefaultInstance(JasperCompileManager.java:197)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:572)
    at pruebajasperreport.PruebaJasperReport.crearInforme(PruebaJasperReport.java:49)
    at pruebajasperreport.PruebaJasperReport.main(PruebaJasperReport.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: como esta declarando tu pom.xml

Comment: El error marca que la clase LogFactoy no fue encontrada, podrias postear tu pom.xml o revisar tus dependencias, la clase LogFactory se encuentra en la siguiente dependencia de Apache Commons Logging: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging